# What it is compatible version of springfox-version will work with spring-boot-parent 2.3.3 + and starter-web 5.3.0?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Getting UndefinedBeanException or Instance creation issue for swagger, springfox, When using below combinations:

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.3.RELEASE

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web
5.3.0

io.springfox
springfox-swagger2
2.5.0

io.springfox
springfox-swagger-ui
2.5.0

Please share any recommendation & suggestion for the spring boot compatible version.

Comment: Tried with swagger 3.0.0 version still getting same issue, Build is not successful.

Comment: What error is coming? Can you please share that in question